# Rank mismatch in array reference when reading data from a table

Tags: fortran

I have a text file with the following format (11 columns and 8 rows)

```
Name    Chris    Kyle    Peter    Luke    Sally (...)   
age     xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
height          xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
weight          xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
class           xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
```

The first column (chris) only has data in the first row.

I need to build a program to read this table, this is what I have so far but I can't get it to work...

```
  program readtable

  implicit none
  integer :: i, j, num_col, num_row
  double precision, dimension (2) :: a
  character(14), dimension (1) :: variable

  num_col = 11
  num_row = 8

  open(100,file='SSL.dat',status='old')
  do j=1, num_row

        read(100,*) variable(j), (a(i,j), i=1,num_col)
        print*, variable(j), a(i,j)

  end do

  end program
```

When I run this piece of code I get a rank mismatch.

I want to read the data in this table so that I can then assign the data to specific variables. For instance, If I want to do some stuff with kyle and Peter I know that for Kyle a(:,2) and for Peter a(:,3)

Here is the error I get when I compile with gfortran as a Fortran 90 code

```
               read(100,*) variable(j), (a(i,j),i=1,num_col))
                                         1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (2/1)
```

Comment: Please give us the exact error messages you are getting and the command that causes them.

Comment: Please copy it as a text. It should be searchable for other people. This is the reason why you cannot put the image directly into the question. I will not edit it to make the picture visible eventhough I can. Put a text here instead. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Is this version ok?

Comment: yes, it is OK now. The gfortran command would be better, but this time it is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you assume that `dimension(n)` makes the array `n`-dimensional.  That is not true! It make s the array one-dimensional and with shape from 1 to `n`, i.e., `(1:n)`.

If you want to declare a two-dimensional array with 8 rows and 11 columns you have to do:

```
double precision, dimension(8,11) :: a
```

or equivalently

```
double precision :: a(8,11)
```

Similarly, `variable` must be something like:

```
character(14), dimension(8) :: variable
```

This will not make your program complete and functional, but will fix the immediate issue the compiler is complaining about. Please keep your questions narrow.